# Images are visible only when i resize the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imageflow

Hi I am using ImageFlow plugin in my website to add cover flow effect to set of images. I have gone through the documentation and tried with different examples they works fine but the major problem is that images are invisible when i first load the page, but appears as soon as i resize the browser window size manually by mouse. Below is the code where i used Imageflow class.

```
     <div id="unique_name" class="imageflow"> 
           <?php foreach ($ABC['A'] as $ABC) : ?>
               <img src="../<?= $ABC['dir'] . $ABC['image'] ?>" width="200" height="200" />
           <?php endforeach; ?>
     </div>
```

Comment: try to put a space before `width` like that : `<img src="../<?= $ABC['dir'] . $ABC['image'] ?>" width="200" height=200" />`

Comment: No i don't find any change in the result. @Mehdi Karamosly

Comment: fix `height="200"` and try to provide relative path to the root folder of your web application.

Comment: Which browser does it happen in? IE? Firefox? Chrome? All of them?